# Different date format?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Why doesn't excel let me change the date format in one of my columns? Basically, I have a date format on two columns in an excel sheet. Column "D" 9/2/2013 m/d/yyyy and column "E" 17/9/2013 d/m/yyyy. The problem is that I am able to change the format in column "D" to any date format but cant do so in column "E".

What is going on?

Comment: If the cells in column **E** are resistant to format change, they are probably Text rather than genuine dates.  They can be converted into real dates with a simple macro.  Is this approach acceptable??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent the approach would be acceptable.

Comment: @pnuts dont really know if that was formatted as text but seems like no matter what I do it wont change...

Comment: @pnuts get a Value error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select only those cells that need to be fixed and run:

```
Sub FixDates()
    Dim D As Date
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        s = r.Text
        ary = Split(s, "/")
        D = DateSerial(ary(2), ary(1), ary(0))
        r.Value = D
        r.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Great Works like a Charm...

Comment: You are quite welcome......thanks for the feedback.